# Saving Notes when I change an Android phone

Tags: backup, google-account, xiaomi, notes

I have a Xiaomi MI3 and I'll buy the new Xiaomi MI6. In my current phone I have many notes (about 150 notes that I have to save).

Is there a way to save notes in order to have them in the next phone? Because I dont'know how to save them using the google account or the Mi account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using some specific note taking app (i.e., google keep, color note)? If yes, these app has exporting options inbuilt, check out.

[Color note backup and sync](https://www.colornote.com/sync-notes-between-phone-and-tablet/)